# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as', but line has no 'as'

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax, ssms

I am altering a stored procedure, and when I try to excecute, I get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vtg_asmbltimephasedashassy, Line 20  
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
```

But when I go to line 20, there is no keyword 'as', nor is it in the line directly before or after line 20.  Maybe I am counting the lines wrong.

When I am counting to line 20 I get the line that reads

```
jobmtl.partnum=partwhse.partnum FULL OUTER JOIN
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as what I need to do to resolve the issue?  My enitre stored procedure follows below.

```
USE [mfgsys803]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[vtg_asmbltimephasedashassy]    Script Date:   01/08/2013 12:59:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[vtg_asmbltimephasedashassy] @p_plant varchar(max) 
as 
begin 
set nocount on;

SELECT     jobhead.jobnum, sum(partwhse.onhandqty) as 'onhandqty', jobhead.partnum, jobhead.revisionnum, jobhead.prodqty, jobhead.startdate, jobhead.duedate, jobhead.reqduedate, 
                  jobhead.commenttext, jobmtl.issuedcomplete, jobmtl.issuedqty, jobmtl.mtlseq, jobmtl.partnum AS 'mtlpart', jobmtl.requiredqty, jobmtl.qtyper, jobmtl.reqdate, 
                  partwhse.warehousecode, prodgrup.description
FROM         jobmtl LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  partwhse INNER JOIN
                  warehse ON partwhse.company = warehse.company AND partwhse.warehousecode = warehse.warehousecode ON jobmtl.company = partwhse.company AND 
                  jobmtl.partnum = partwhse.partnum FULL OUTER JOIN
                  prodgrup INNER JOIN
                  jobhead ON prodgrup.company = jobhead.company AND prodgrup.prodcode = jobhead.prodcode ON jobmtl.company = jobhead.company AND 
                  jobmtl.jobnum = jobhead.jobnum
WHERE     (jobhead.jobreleased = 0) AND (jobhead.jobfirm = 1) AND (jobhead.jobengineered = 1) AND (jobhead.company = 'lot') and  (prodgrup.description like '%assy%') and (jobhead.plant=@p_plant) and (warehse.plant=@p_plant)

group by     jobhead.jobnum, jobhead.partnum, jobhead.revisionnum, jobhead.prodqty, jobhead.startdate, jobhead.duedate, jobhead.reqduedate, 
                  jobhead.commenttext, jobmtl.issuedcomplete, jobmtl.issuedqty, jobmtl.mtlseq, jobmtl.partnum AS 'mtlpart', jobmtl.requiredqty, jobmtl.qtyper, jobmtl.reqdate, 
                  partwhse.warehousecode, prodgrup.description


end
```

Comment: In SQL Server, the error is reported on the line where the *statement* starts. So if, somehow, you create a single statement spanning 1000 lines, and there's an error in the last line, the error will be reported at the first line.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - That isn't true for parse errors. It is line 20 following the `GO` so it is 20th line in the batch submitted. `@Jennifer` double clicking the error message would take you to the offending line.

Comment: @MartinSmith - an error at the 1000th line in a batch, where the statement starts at line 1 in the batch will be reported as an error at line 1. The point I was trying to make is, just relying on the reported line number doesn't help people with locating the error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes a runtime error would but this is a syntax error so in this case it does help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take this part out of the group by

```
jobmtl.partnum AS 'mtlpart'
```

make it

```
jobmtl.partnum
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!! As soon as it will let me I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The line number simply rtefers to the line number of the SQL statement containing the error... Which is the entire Select statement.   The As is in the Group By at `jobmtl.partnum AS 'mtlpart',` and needs to come out.